# How to save rdd action in textfile? Scala/Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I have an rdd of strings how can i store Rdd action on textfile? or how to pass see it on console,Driver program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yourRDD.saveAsTextFile("path")
```

.saveAsTextFile() method will write the data to simple text files where the .toString() method is called on each RDD element and one element is written per line. The number of files output is equal to the the number of partitions of the RDD being saved.